# Merging multiple file copy backups

Tags: backup, filesystems

I have a series of backups (manually made) that contain duplicate information, is there any program/script/command to iterate through the directory structure identify duplicate files via MD5 hashes and then remove one of the files?

Either Windows/Linux solutions will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I use [rdfind](http://rdfind.pauldreik.se) for this. As mentioned in the linked page, there are plenty of other tools for this and I've tried most of them, but rdfind has the optimisation of scanning the first and last few bytes of each file first, and only computing the MD5 sum if these are identical, which on my backups makes this way faster than anything else I've tried.

For the usage you request, you will want to run

```
rdfind --deleteduplicates backup_a backup_b
```

However I would recommend you run it with the -makehardlinks option. This will replace the duplicate files with hard links (assuming you're storing the data on a sane file system) so that each backup will look as it does now, but with duplicate data only stored once.

Comment: Thank you. Great to know that someone else has the exact same backup strategy as me.